# Generic type cannot be used as type parameter in another generic type when type constraints match

Tags: c#, generics, mvvm, abstract-class

I have an application where I want to use the MVVM pattern to have a separation between `View components` (UI-specific) and `ViewModel components` (non-UI-specific).

For example, I have a scenario where there can be different `Grid` classes (UI-specific) for displaying different data that take in a `GridViewModel` class as a generic type parameter (non-UI-specific). To avoid repeated code, I wanted to define some abstract and generic base classes for both types of components but somehow I failed to wrap my head around the generics.

This is a rough outline of my idea in code:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class EditableGrid<T> : BaseGrid<T> 
    where T : IEditableGrid<IEditableRow> {
    
    public EditableGrid(T editableVirtualGrid) : base(editableVirtualGrid) {
    }
}


public abstract class BaseGrid<T> 
    where T : IVirtualGrid<IVirtualRow> {
    
    public T VirtualGrid {get;}
    
    protected BaseGrid(T virtualGrid) { 
        VirtualGrid = virtualGrid;
    }
}
```

Generic grid interfaces

```cs
public interface IEditableGrid<TRow> : IVirtualGrid<TRow> 
    where TRow : IEditableRow {
}

public interface IVirtualGrid<TRow> 
    where TRow : IVirtualRow {
    ICollection<TRow> Rows {get;}
}
```

Row interfaces

```cs
public interface IEditableRow : IVirtualRow {}

public interface IVirtualRow {}
```

When I try to define the `EditableGrid` class I get the following compile-time error:

> error CS0314: The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the
> generic type or method 'BaseGrid'. There is no boxing conversion or
> type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'IVirtualGrid'

Shouldn't that be allowed since the type `T` is constrained to `IEditableGrid` which inherits from `IVirtualGrid`?

Comment: No, `IEditableGrid<IEditableRow>` is not a `IVirtualGrid<IVirtualRow>`. You can insert anything that implements `IVirtualRow`  into the rows of `IVirtualGrid<IVirtualRow>`, but you can only insert *editable* rows into the rows of `IEditableGrid<IEditableRow>`.

Comment: Read through the ***fruit*** example in the duplicate question. Let me know if that makes it clear for you.

Comment: @Enigmativity I think I understand the problem better now. I wonder how to tackle a scenario where I would need a covariant and contravariant generic parameter at the same time. For example, if my grid interface returns all the rows it contains and also allows the user to select rows by passing an instance of the row:
`public interface IVirtualGrid<out TRow>  where TRow : IVirtualRow {
    IEnumerable<TRow> Rows {get;}
    SelectRow(TRow rowToSelect);
}`